# I want to Access data in Laravel where foreign table key news.status = 1 from the table "newscategory"

Tags: php, laravel

I used this code previously.

```
$datacategory = NewsCategory::with('news:id,slug,title,nepalidate,featured_image,status')->where('category_id',$id)->orderBy('news_id','asc')->limit(3)->get();
```

Now I was to access this query by using where clause for the status of foreign news table. I tried following code but it doesn't work.

```
$datacategory = NewsCategory::with('news:id,slug,title,nepalidate,featured_image,status')->where('category_id',$id)->where('news.status', 1)->orderBy('news_id','asc')->limit(3)->get();
```

Comment: do you want to only eager load 'news' that have a particular 'status' or do you want to restrict the 'NewsCategory' set to only ones that have news with a particular 'status'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `whereHas` to filter the relationship:

```
$datacategory = NewsCategory::with('news:id,slug,title,nepalidate,featured_image,status')->where('category_id',$id)->whereHas('news', function($query){
    $query->where('status', 1);
})->orderBy('news_id','asc')->limit(3)->get();
```